# What is solar storm?

Tags: astrophysics

I have tried to search through the internet about the definition of solar storm or what this term mean but i could found what it means. Also, what is the difference between the geomagnetic storm

Comment: Wikipedia tells you the answer so I do not know how have you searched through the internet...

Comment: did you try to type solar storm in wiki, if no, try it, it didn't show a page about solar storm

Comment: Indeed I did, you've got explained the solar flares which occur at the Sun's surface and the geomagnetic storms which include the disturbances caused by the solar wind to the Earth magnetosphere.

Comment: Two downvotes seems a bit harsh - not everyone is a physics geek like us! I've upvoted to cancel one of the downvotes.

Comment: @John Not in this case. The problem with this question has nothing to do with anyone being a physics geek or not; rather, it shows a complete lack of effort on the part of the questioner. As DaniH said, and as you yourself pointed out in your answer, typing "solar storm" into Wikipedia leads you straight to the relevant article. Mathematics, if you had said in the question that you had done this, and explained why the article you found didn't answer your question, it would have been a better question.

Comment: Well, ias you said, it only shows relevant pages but didn't give exact meaning to the term. The point is I am searching for the exact meaning to the terms instead of some relevant information. If you read carefully, those pages still didn't give the definiton or explain about the solar storm

Comment: *"I've upvoted to cancel one of the downvotes."* Without my moderator hat on (because mods don't get to tell people how to vote) I consider this to be one of the worst reasons to vote for a post going. Either vote for it on *your assessment of its merits* or don't vote at all.

Comment: Mathematics, three possible definitions are given _directly_ on the disambiguation page for "solar storm" - and that is in addition to the detailed explanations on the wiki pages themselves. It seems hard to justify the claim that Wikipedia doesn't give the exact meaning. In any case, doing prior research is a prerequisite to asking a question here. Even if the Wikipedia pages don't answer your question, you should mention that you looked at them and explain why they don't answer your question.

Comment: By the way if you'd like to continue discussing this, ping me in [chat] and we'll continue it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "solar storm" is a term more likely to be used by a newspaper than a helioseismologist. As far as the term has any strict meaning, it means the same as the rather better defined term "geomagnetic storm". This is a disturbance to the Earth's magnetic field caused when charged particles from the sun hit the Earth's magnetic field. As usual, Wikipedia has an excellent article on this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm. Incidentally, I note that if you search for "solar storm" on Wikipedia it redirects you to the "geomagnetic storm" article.

Comment: Quote you, "search for "solar storm" on Wikipedia it redirects you to the "geomagnetic storm""             And 7 other options. Maybe we were a bit hard on Mathematics.